# Add paramater to redux useSelector hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am learning Typescript and I have created a smalle app with

```
create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript
```

That has created a hook to type the useSelector

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook,useSelector } from 'react-redux';
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

With the useAppSelector i want to select something from the store with a parameter

```
const favouriteList = useAppSelector((listKey) => selectFavouriteList(listKey));
```

Without Typescript I thought I could solve this with currying.

```
const selectFavouriteList = (state: RootState) => (listKey: string) => {
            return state.favourites.lists[listKey]
        }
```

But TypesScript returns this error, it expects the store as parameter.

```
Argument of type 'DefaultRootState' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ favourites: favouriteListState; }'.
  Property 'favourites' is missing in type 'DefaultRootState' but required in type '{ favourites: favouriteListState; }'.ts(2345)
store.ts(8, 9): 'favourites' is declared here.
```

Does anyone has a suggestion how to sole this :-)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do it this way:

```
const favouriteList = useAppSelector((state) => selectFavouriteList(state, listKey));
```

where `listKey` is a local varaible.

If you want to curry, do it the other way round:

```
const selectFavouriteList = (listKey: string) => (state: RootState) => {
            return state.favourites.lists[listKey]
}

const favouriteList = useAppSelector(selectFavouriteList(listKey));
```

Comment: Thank, passing the state to the selector did the trick